# String Question

Tags: string-manipulation

Consider:

```
listOfScores = 
 Import["http://www.handsonstart.com/ExampleDataScores.txt", "Data"]
```

Which gives this output:

```
{{"Joe", "Smith", 94}, {"Jane", "Smith", 85}, {"Bob", "Example", 
  82}, {"Bill", "Student", 83}, {"Michelle", "Abacus", 98}}
```

Now this gives me what I want but with an error message:

```
listOfScores /. {x_, y_, z_} -> StringJoin[x, " ", y]
```

StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in x<> <>y. >>

StringJoin::string: String expected at position 3 in x<> <>y. >>

```
{"Joe Smith", "Jane Smith", "Bob Example", "Bill Student", "Michelle \
Abacus"}
```

Then I tried:

```
listOfScores /. {x_, y_, z_} -> StringQ[x]
```

Which gave:

```
{False, False, False, False, False}
```

Yet this:

```
StringQ /@ listOfScores[[All, 1]]
```

Gives me this:

```
{True, True, True, True, True}
```

A bit confusing. Can someone provide an explanation?

Comment: Use `:>` instead of `->`.

Comment: JM's solution fixes it, but if you're still confused don't sorry, I am too. I'd really be interested to hear an explanation as to why `->` causes the difference versus `:>`

Comment: @mathers101 The ->StringQ[x] immediately analyses StringQ[x] before making the substitution. Try Clear[x] then StringQ[x] and watch what happens. However, the :>StringQ[x] is a "delayed" replacement. So I am thinking it inserts the replacement for x before evaluating the StringQ command.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the nice answer. Learned a lot.

Comment: David, your last comment could be an answer. ;)